# add elements into a data structure without knowing the data size in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I would like to use a data structure to save data (double) in R on win 7.

But, the data size may be 100k or less. I do not know the size of the data. So, I cannot give a length to the data structure.

I just need to save them in a data structure in R.

I have tried list, but i got:

```
> x <- list()
> str(x)
> append(x, 10)
  [[1]]
  [1] 10

> append(x, 50)
  [[1]]
  [1] 50
> length(x)
   [1] 0
```

I also tried vector

```
> y <- vector()
> str(y)
  logi(0) 
> append(y, 8)
  [1] 8
> length(y)
  [1] 0
```

**update**

example,

```
I have data, 89.601 , 56.302 , 7.231 ,  ....
```

I need to read them from a file and then save them in a data structure in R so that I can use them later.

I also need to use the data to do a qq-plot. A list or a vector, which one is better for the plot ? thanks !

I just want to optimize the space and performance at the same time. Loading the whole file into a data.frame once in R is better than reading and then processing the file line by line ?  **What if the whole file size has 120 million numbers/strings ?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list or vector of a given length with all its elements set to some default value?

Comment: @joran, no, I need to save the numbers into a data structure. I do not know the exact size of the data. So, I cannot pre-define a length for the data structure. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I can't make any sense of this question at all. What are you trying to achieve with your example code, which creates an empty vector and then appends a value (but does not keep the result)?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? File on disk, data base, etc?

Comment: If the data exists in a file on disk, why haven't any of the tools for reading data into R worked? `read.table`, `scan`, `readLines`, `fread` (data.table package). Reading files in from disk does not require creating a data structure in R in advance.

Comment: yes, I know. But, the data file is very large. I need to process it line by line and save the result (just a number) in a data structure. The data file size is not known. Thanks !

Comment: Reading a file one line at a time is not a typical R usage pattern. A max size of 100k is not terribly large. That much data could _easily_ and quickly be read into memory using standard R functions. I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually slower to read the file one line at a time.

Comment: I just want to optimize the sapce and performance at the same time. Loading the whole file into a data.frame once in R is better than reading and then processing the file line by line ? Thanks !

Comment: Almost certainly yes. And iteratively adding elements (i.e. "growing") a vector (the solution you tried, and in the answer below) is not just slow, it is quite possibly the slowest thing you could possibly do in R. That's why I originally asked you about pre-allocating a data structure of some set size (even if its way too big).

Comment: @joran, I appreciate, would you please tell me the reason why loading a whole file is faster than processing line-by-line ? What if the whole file size is 120 million numbers/strings ?  Thanks !

Comment: May I create a new thread for the new question of how to processing large data file ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't storing your result.  R is similar to the functional programming paradigm.  So in this case what you need is:

```
x <- list()
x <- append(x, 10)
x <- append(x, 50)
```

Then type `length(x)` and see what you get.

Comment: it works ! I need to use the data to do a qq-plot. A list or a vector, which one is better for the plot ? thanks !

Comment: vector and be careful with this approach.  If you have a lot of data it will go slowly.  Not sure how you're doing this, though.  Please choose it as an answer as well :)